# Basic sampling of joint random variables

Tags: probability, sampling

If random variables $X \in \mathcal X$ and $Y \in \mathcal Y$ are sampled jointly from a target distribution $\pi$, i.e. $(X, Y) \sim \pi(x, y)$, is $X$ sampled from the correct marginal?

In other words, is $(X, Y) \sim \pi(x, y) \implies X \sim \pi(x)$ true?

Can anyone please refer me to a book which contains the full proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X, Y) \sim \pi(x, y) \iff \forall A \subseteq \mathcal X, B \subseteq \mathcal Y$:

$$\mathbb P(X \in A, Y \in B) = \int_B \int_A \pi(x, y) dx dy.$$

Fix $C \subseteq \mathcal X$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X \in C) &= \mathbb P(X \in C, Y \in \mathcal Y) \\
&= \int_C \int_{\mathcal Y} \pi(x, y) dy dx \\
&= \int_C \pi(x) dx
\end{align}
$\iff X \sim \pi(x)$.

Comment: Isn't this what I just said? The joint distribution defines the marginal, so sampling from $(X,Y)$ automatically samples $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I didn't understand how it was automatic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. For example, see the [Fundamental Theorem of Simulation](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~xian/madrid.pdf) (slide 98). If you generate pairs $(X,Y)$ and ignore $Y$, you are effectively marginalizing over $Y$

Robert and Casella's book is really great if you're into Monte Carlo simulation for statistics.

At a more basic level, it is true that the joint distribution defines the marginal distribution (so your statement is generally true)...however the converse is only true for independent random variables (or Multivariate Gaussian).

**Demonstration that $(X, Y) \sim \pi(x, y) \implies X \sim \pi(x)$**

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$

$$X\in I \iff (X,Y)\in [I,\mathbb{R}] \implies P(X\in I)=P((X,Y)\in [I,\mathbb{R}])$$

But, $P((x,Y)\in [I,\mathbb{R}])=1,\forall x \in I \implies P(X\in I)$ depends only on the value of $X$, as it should for a marginal distribution.

This [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) might also be helpful:

$$\pi_X(x):=\int \pi_{XY}(x,y) dy$$

Comment: Slide 98 generates pairs of $(X, Y)$ from a uniform distribution with the support $\{(x, u): 0 < u < f(x)\}$ which is not the same as generating them from a more general target distribution $\pi$ with support $\mathcal X \times \mathcal Y$.

Comment: @sk1ll3r you are correct. It justifies acceptance-rejection methods. See my second full paragraph in my post. The joint pdf always defines the marginals, so throwing out other dimensions after simulating will marginalize your data.

Comment: Why is this the case? Yes, joint pdf always defines marginal pdfs. How does this imply "throwing out other dimensions after simulating will marginalise your data"?

Comment: @sk1ll3r not sure what type of repsonse you're looking for, but above is my attempt at a rigorous demonstration. Note that, by definition, if you generate pairs from a joint distribution, then the individual components *must* produce the correct marginal.

Comment: @sk1ll3r ok, then just think about what it means to have a marginal distribution then. A marginal distribution is simply the projection of the joint distribution on one of the axes, right? So, from that perspective, you don't see the Y values, so they might as well be ignored. The joint distribution defines the marginals, since the marginal is the integral of the joint distribution over one of the variables.

Comment: I don't quite understand your demonstration. I'm probably looking for something like this:
</br>
For the implication to hold, it suffices to prove:
$\forall A \subset \mathcal X, B \subset \mathcal Y$ the probability of $(X, Y)$ landing in $A \times B$ is $\mathbb P(X \in A, Y \in B) = \pi(A, B)$.
</br>
implies
</br>
$\forall C \subset \mathcal X$, the probability of the same $X$ landing in $C$ is $\mathbb P(X \in C) = \pi(C)$.
</br>
where $\pi(S) = \int_S \pi(x)dx$ for a set $S$ in the support of x.

Comment: @sk1ll3r This is true...the joint distribution *implies* the marginal distributions, as marginal distributions are defined in relation to their joint distribution.

Comment: @sk1ll3r I've updated my post.

Comment: Could you perhaps include a rigorous proof or the explicit logical steps that are taken assuming only the definitions? Or point me to some resource?

Comment: never mind. got it.

Comment: @sk1ll3r my demonstration starts from your assumptions and the definition of a marginal distribution. Sounds like you're all set though.